# Translating curl -v --data command

Tags: c, http, post, curl

I already created a simple server in `c` that responds to `curl` requests. What I want to do now is to make the same request using normal `sockets`, without the abstraction of a library.

So now I am trying to translate this curl command:

```
λ server → curl -v --data "value=2" localhost:5000/19
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 5000 (#0)
> POST /19 HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
> Host: localhost:5000
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 7
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
* upload completely sent off: 7 out of 7 bytes
...
...
```

Is the translation provided by `-v` verbose argument complete?
In the request, I can only see the path `19` passed in. Where is the argument `"value=2"`?

Also, the camp `Content-Length` is set to `7`. This is also strange, because the body seems to be empty. What am I getting wrong here?

Comment: The output is not showing the body.

Answer (score 0):

> What am I getting wrong here?

You failed to read the `curl` manual:

```
   -v/--verbose
          Makes the fetching more  verbose/talkative.  Mostly  useful  for
          debugging.  A line starting with '>' means "header data" sent by
          curl, '<' means "header data" received by curl that is hidden in
          normal cases, and a line starting with '*' means additional info
          provided by curl.
          …
          If  you think this option still doesn't give you enough details,
          consider using --trace or --trace-ascii instead.
```

So,

```
curl --trace-ascii - --data "value=2" localhost:5000/19
```

shows the body data.